Help me intuit Equal Probabilities in Poisson Distribution for $k = λ$ and $k = λ-1$
I was trying to understand Poisson distribution and I'm confused as to why the likelihood of $k=λ-1$ is equal to $k=λ$. Here is my understanding and where my confusion is:
For a given time interval, if you know the expected rate at which an event occurs, you can get the probability of that event occurring k times with the following formula:
$$
\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}
$$
So if I receive an email on average once every hour, my $λ = 1$, and if I'm wondering how likely am I to receive 0 emails, 1 email, or 2 emails, I get the following:

$k=0$, probability=~0.368
$k=1$, probability=~0.368
$k=2$, probability=~0.184

This surprised me at first, because I thought that 0 would be just as likely as 2. However, after realizing that if I'm equally likely to receive <1 email as I am >1 email, it made sense that $k=2$ could only share a portion of that probability, while $k=0$ could take all of that probability.
After this though, I discovered that no matter what number I entered as λ, the likelihood probability of $k=λ$ was always equal to the probability of $k=λ-1$. Now, I understand that $k<λ$ sort of have a bias, but I assumed as λ increased, $λ-1$ would approach $λ+1$.
I have now learned that yes, $k=λ-1$ will always equal $k=λ$, I'm led to believe that the extra λ is canceled out in the factorial of the denominator. I'm sorry if that isn't 100% correct, but essentially I understand and believe that $k=λ-1$ will always equal $k=λ$.
My issue is in understanding that intuitively. If you have a λ, you know THE mean/mode of occurrences, why would one less than that also be just as likely to occur? I feel like this is a bias in the equation, right?
Wikipedia told me the assumptions of a Poisson distribution are:

k is the number of times an event occurs in an interval and k can take values 0, 1, 2, ...
The occurrence of one event does not affect the probability that a second event will occur. That is, events occur independently
The average rate at which events occur is independent of any occurrences. For simplicity, this is usually assumed to be constant, but may in practice vary with time
Two events cannot occur at exactly the same instant; instead, at each very small sub-interval, either exactly one event occurs, or no event occurs

And if these conditions are true, then k is a Poisson random variable, and the distribution of k is a Poisson distribution.
What am I missing? What am I not getting?

For the Poisson distribution only if $\lambda$ is an integer, we have
$$\mathbb P (X=\lambda)= \mathbb P (X=\lambda-1).$$
In fact, these are both the modes of the distribution. If $\lambda$ is NOT integeral, the above does not hold. In this case, the mode is $\lfloor \lambda \rfloor$.
The above can be seen easily from the following recursive relation:
$$\mathbb P (X=k)= \frac{ \lambda}{k}\mathbb P (X=k-1).$$

Okay, I think I finally understand it. My issue was that I was equating λ with both the mean and the mode. Within a Poisson distribution, the mean and the mode aren't equal. When you state λ, you are stating the average, not the mode.
The other part of why this was confusing to me is I assumed the probability of any k < λ was equal to the probability of any k > λ, but that isn't the case.
That is why the mean will be a higher number than the mode. Because the probability of the right side of the mode is slightly higher, the mean shifts to the right. This shift is systematically 0.5 higher than the mode, causing the mean and the mean-1 to be equally probable.
